# How do I read in a CSV file from my desktop in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read in a CSV file from my desktop:

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pathlib import Path

csv = r'C:\Users\nulli\OneDrive\Desktop\Work_Sample.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=',')
```

Error:

```
---> df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=',')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\nulli\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Work_Sample.csv'
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your path `C:Users\nulli\OneDrive\Desktop\Work_Sample.csv` should be `C:\Users\nulli\OneDrive\Desktop\Work_Sample.csv`.

Comment: If you want to be entirely sure of the path, go to your file explorer, right click on your file > properties > location, and copy this.

Comment: @ndclt ahh that is definitely part of the problem. I now get an error of csv = 'C:\Users\nulli\OneDrive\Desktop\Work_Sample.csv' ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use backslashes for paths as Python has some special escape characters like `\n` that means newline or `\t` that means a tab. The easiest way is to always use standard slashes. You can also use:

```py
r"some_path\with\backslashes"
```

to ignore escape characters and treat all backslashes as backslashes.

But the best way is to use a package which was designed to handle paths. [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a great tool for that:

```py
from pathlib import Path
my_csv = Path("C:/Usersnulli/OneDrive/Desktop/Work_Sample.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(my_csv.resolve(), sep=',')
```

`resolve()` returns a `str` from Path object.

And I think that it is often better to use relative paths - they will work for everyone without the need to update them. You can for example create a `data` folder in your workspace with the script and put the file there.

Also, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/14458327) out for more details regarding paths in Python.

Comment: So @trivvz correct me if I am misunderstanding but best practice would be to try:  os.path.join('C:\Users\nulli\OneDrive\Desktop\, Work_Sample.csv')

Comment: I'll suggest always using standard slashes and the library. So it should be (you have a missing `):

os.path.join("C:/Users/nulli/OneDrive/Desktop", "Work_Sample.csv")

Comment: Probably, it is also better nowadays to use pathlib rather than os.path. It is newer and it is easier to do more complicated stuff with it.

Comment: so something similar to what anurag has said? My only problem with that is I get a no such file in directory when I try to read in my pd.read_csv line

Comment: @iceAtNight, the following is the simplest that will work: csv = r'C:\Users\nulli\OneDrive\Desktop\Work_Sample.csv'. But notice that you imported the module with the same name. If you would like to use it later, it won't be possible as your string overwrites it. Always choose different names for your variables - it's a good practice

Comment: Gotcha! This is odd because I am still having a no such file in directory error at df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=',')

Comment: @iceAtNight maybe try using a relative path instead? It's usually an easier and better idea. So put the file in the same folder where you have your Python script and use the filename as the path (no slashes needed :D)

Comment: shoot! I am using google Colab so I am basically working from an online notebook

Comment: Oh, so we got the answer. Colab doesn't see any of your folders and files :) But it should be possible to upload files to Colab. Check this out: https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-load-csv-files-into-colab-7c14fcbdcb92

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path

csv = str(Path('C:\\Users\\nulli\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Work_Sample.csv'))
```

Comment: to be clear I am using                              
       csv_file = str(Path('C:\\Users\\nulli\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Work_Sample.csv'))
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=',')                           is what I want to be using with obviously from pathlib import Path at the top? I still get a no such file in directory error for this when I use pd.read_csv?
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=',')

Comment: are you on windows or linux? Is the path correct?

Comment: I am on windows using google colab, the path should be correct. I have updated the question if that helps. So you should be able to see what I am trying as of now

Comment: is the file on your desktop or on colab? And are you running your code on local machine or on colab? colab is running on google's servers, you have to first upload the file.

Comment: I actually just got it! I needed to upload the file in colab!

Answer (score 0):

After adding the slash after `'C:'`, I would recommend trying `/`'s instead of `\`'s in your path.